# Spark ML: Smooth input data

Tags: apache-spark, filtering, apache-spark-ml, smoothing, noise-reduction

By developing a new ML project with Spark, we want to first smooth input data in order to have less noise (and then better results as we might train with few data).

Strangely, I can find no smoothing filter into Spark-ML (like Kalman eg). Do the Spark-ML users developed their own, or don't they filter input data first? Are there such implementations?

Answer (score 0):

There are third party libraries for Java or Scala that you can import.

Comment: Do you have examples of such libraries?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dd3/tutorial_gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html